# What functions should I know for testing php code?

Tags: php, debugging

I have been using php for a while but haven't taken the time to learn methods that will help test code, debug and investigate problems.

A recently learnt `print_r()` which has really helped me in displaying array data. If I had have known this before, my coding life would have been much easier.

I would like to ask what help functions the members of stackoverflow use regularly for their php coding.

Comment: `var_dump` and `var_export` also display arrays and objects in a neatly formatted way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [print_r()](http://php.net/print_r)
- [var_dump()](http://php.net/var_dump)
- [ob_start()](http://php.net/ob_start) & cie.
- [exit()](http://php.net/exit)
- [error_reporting()](http://php.net/error_reporting)
- [debug_backtrace()](http://php.net/debug_backtrace)
- [debug_print_backtrace()](http://php.net/debug_print_backtrace)
- and more generally some of [these functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.errorfunc.php).
- and why not some of [these](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.info.php)

Answer (score 1):

The most valuable tool I can think of besides `print_r() / var_dump()` is [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/), which will provide stack traces on screen and improved, colorized output to `var_dump()`, as well as code profiling.  I cannot imagine working without Xdebug.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know how to access server logs?

Var dump will give results similar to print_r()

```
var_dump()
```

you can also do this:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($some_array);
echo '</pre>';
```

which will make your print_r much more readable

And also a development server or playground so you don't do this on a live site